# multiple div's on hover animating the width with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question. I'm trying to create an effect where a `div` is expanding percentage wise on hover while the other `div`s in the same container are shrinking.

This is what I've got so far,

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/N6L5E/6/)

Not much, I'm aware.

The desired effect is quite simple. You hover, the width changes from 25% to 40% and back when hover out.

Does anybody know of anyway to make this possible?

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="een">een</div>
    <div class="twee">twee</div>
    <div class="drie">drie</div>
    <div class="vier">vier</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper div {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    height:300px;
}
.wrapper .een {background:#ccc;}
.wrapper .twee {background:#ddd;}
.wrapper .drie {background:#333;}
.wrapper .vier {background:#666;}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $(".wrapper > div").hover(

    function () {
        $(".wrapper > div").animate({
            width: '20%'
        });
        $(this).animate({
            width: '40%'
        });
    },

    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '25%'
        });
        $(".wapper > div").animate({
            width: '25%'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you are calling the effect to run on the siblings, rather than the element itself.

```
$(function () {
     $(".wrapper > div").hover(function () {
         $(this).stop().animate({
             width: '40%'
         }, 500);
     }).mouseout(function(){
         $(this).stop().animate({
             width: '25%'
         }, 500);
     });
});
```

By calling the animation onHover and onMouseOut, you can use `$(this)` to target the hovered element. Simply stop the animations and animate it's width to the proper size over an interval of 0.5s.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N6L5E/7/)

Comment: hi david, thanks so much, this works way better. Do you know of any way that it doesn't break the wrapper when resizing?

Comment: Also, it works perfectly when hovering, but the idea is that the wrapping container stays in place, thus, resizing the 'not being hovered' elements back to 20%.

Comment: Well it was only breaking because you had it set to go back to 25%, and 25%*3 + 40% = 115%, which is greater than 100%. If you make it 20%, [**it works**](http://jsfiddle.net/N6L5E/8/)

Comment: Thanks David, your answer works. Although it's not exactly the desired effect I had in mind. Let me elaborate: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N6L5E/9/). The 'divs' should always expand to 100% of its parent wrapper. So **non-hover state** -> all div's are 25% , and **hover state** -> one div is 40%, the rest 20%. And this all without breaking the parent. Is this possible? Last question I promise!

Comment: again almost perfect! :) It works great with fixed width!, any idea how to handle a 100% width? I made a new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9WF6/) with hoverIntent plugin to make for a more smooth transition.